# Set Datetime order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Is there any way of manipulate datetime in JavaScript?? I mean, I would like to get a datetime and change to this format ('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A/PM').

This is my code

```
$('#control_day_edit').val(calEvent.start._i)
```

This returns me this: 01/07/2015 05:11 PM But I need it returns me this: 07/01/2015 05:11 PM

Comment: *"This returns me this: 01/07/2015 05:11 PM"* Really? That's surprising. Are you sure `calEvent.start._i` is a `Date`? The usual default `Date`-to-string formatting looks more like `"Wed Jan 07 2015 18:34:54 GMT+0000 (GMT)"` (where I am, naturally your timezone is likely different).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I think that might depend on the OS settings for how to display dates as well.

Comment: @CBroe: Yeah. It's *allowed* to depend on anything, including the whim of the person writing the JavaScript engine; the format of `toString` is not dictated by the spec. :-|

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has virtually no built-in date/time formatting. Instead, you either use the individual methods of `Date` instances (`getHours`, `getMinutes`, etc.) to build your string, or use a library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) which uses them for you.